# Spellchecker using symspellpy

Tags: python

I want to make a spellchecker which can correct user input if any mistakes are there.
I used symspellpy and customs data base for dictionary

```
from symspellpy import SymSpell

sym_spell = SymSpell()
corpus_path = 'D:\Pursuit soft\dict\words2.txt'
sym_spell.create_dictionary(corpus_path)

print(sym_spell.words)
```

now when I am using it with following codes

```
from symspellpy import SymSpell, Verbosity
input_term='cmments'
suggestions = sym_spell.lookup(input_term, Verbosity.CLOSEST,
                               max_edit_distance=2, include_unknown=True)

for suggestion in suggestions:
    print(suggestion)
```

result is:
'cmments' changed into 'comments, 1, 8'..which is correct..but I just only words not distance and frequency ..how to extract only word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of lookup is a list of `SuggestItem`s. You can get just the suggested term via:

```
print(suggestion.term)
```

Comment: The others are `suggestion.count` plus `suggestion.distance` for the number of edits. Besides `CLOSEST` there's also `TOP`. And `ALL` (applying up to the `max_edit_distance`) for when one might want to do some other things with those lesser close matches.